# Matlab command "iztrans"only applicable for causal signals?

Tags: matlab, causality

Matlab command for inverse z transform `iztrans`only applicable for causal signals? or also valid for non causal signals?

Actually i want to find inverse z transform for the cases shown in attached snap and i am  confused if iztrans command is applicable to all of them?
[image]

Comment: If you share with us what you're trying to _do_, we may be of more help.  I.e., if you're working on Wiener filters and need to separate the causal and non-causal parts of the answer, _say so_ and we may be able to help you find a method.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We'll answer it, but only in such a way as to help you get to the answer.  For the three questions you've added since I posted my answer, please let us know how you'd go about establishing whether `iztrans` can help. We can then guide you if you go astray. Please edit your question with this extra information, and ping me and I'll reopen the question. Hint: look up "region of convergence".

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [manual entry from the Mathworks website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.iztrans.html):

[image: Screenshot of iztrans manual.]

the $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ suggests that it's only considering the causal component.

Comment: And their examples give `ans = 2^n + 2^n*(n - 1)`, which says that if they see a pole outside the unit circle they'll interpret it as a causal unstable system, not a non-causal stable one.